# Convert currency $232,680.00 to decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, currency

What will be best way to get decimal value from `$232,680.00` Is it possible without regular expression.

Also this does not work -

```
decimal.TryParse(Response.assess_market_value, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out marketTotalValue);
```

Comment: What exactly is `Response.assess_market_value`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine [`AllowCurrencySymbol`, `AllowDecimalPoint` and `AllowThousands` styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles) and use a culture that has `$` as a [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol) like `en-US`

```
var s = "$232,680.00";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol |
                             NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
                             NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
                             CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

or more simple use `NumberStyles.Currency` instead which contains those styles as well.

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The problem in your code is `InvariantCulture` has `¤` (which is Currency Sign ([`U+00A4`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a4/index.htm))) not `$` as a `CurrencySymbol`. If you change your `InvariantCulture` to `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`, your code will work as well.

`en-US` culture totally fits for your string since it has `.` as a decimal separator and `,` as a thousand separator.

Comment: Using `NumberStyles.Currency` (instead of `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` and `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`) in combination with `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol` is arguably cleaner.

Comment: @Rik `Currency` _already_ contains `AllowCurrencySymbol` so it will be redundant to use it. Just using `Currency` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have about:

```
decimal.Parse("$232,680.00", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```